# laravel can't find the id of main model in many-to-many realtionship

Tags: laravel

I'm using the attach to create many to many relationship.

Article model:

```
class Article extends Model
{
public function sections()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Section::class);
    }
}
```

Section Model:

```
class Section extends Model
{
    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
    }
}
```

attaching sections to the article

```
$sections = [4,6,5];
$article->sections()->attach($sections);
```

the error i'm getting

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'article_id' cannot be null
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO `article_section` (`article_id`, `section_id`) VALUES (?, 5), (?, 6), (?, 7)
> ```

I tried to switch between `attach`, `detach`, and `sync`\
`sync` only accepted the first element from the array and returned the same error with this SQL

```
INSERT INTO `article_section` (`article_id`, `section_id`) VALUES (?, 5), (?, 6), (?, 7)
```

`detach` returned false;

Comment: what is your code for the `$article`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on the `store` method:

```
$article = new Article;
$article->title = 'Some Title';
$article->save();

$article->sections()->sync([4,6,5]);
```

And if you are on the `update` method:

```
$article = Article::find(1);
$article->title = 'Some Title';
$article->save();

$article->sections()->sync([4,6,5]);
```

Answer (score 0):

YOU need to add the pivot table name to the belongsToMany relations and the foreign ids in the table

```
class Article extends Model
{
public function sections()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Section::class,'table_name');
    }
}


class Section extends Model
{
    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class,'table_name');
    }
}
```